# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding element into Hibernate's PersistentSet

Tags: java, hibernate, set, persistence

So I stumbled upon this weird situation.
Got classic JPA entities:

Measurement:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "measurement", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
public Set<ChangeLogItem> getChangeLog() {
    return changeLog;
}
```

ChangeLogItem:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "MEASUREMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "MEASUREMENT_ID")
@ManyToOne
public Mereni getMeasurement() {
    return measurement;
}
```

Entity *Measurement* has utility method:

```
public void addToChangeLog(ChangeLogItem element) {
    if (element == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element ChangeLogItem can't be null");
    }
    getChangeLog().add(element);
    element.setMeasurement(this);
}
```

When this utility method is called AND the Set of *ChangeLogItem* is EMPTY I got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -912523107
  at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:494)
  at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
  at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:213)
```

Now when I manually add some ChangeLogItem into database then the *add()* method works just fine.

**Update:** After some painful debugging I found out that the strange behavior happens inside `java.util.HashMap`. There is code in `public V put(K var1, V var2)` that should expand the underlying table:

```
if (this.table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
    this.inflateTable(this.threshold);
}
```

but in my case the `inflateTable()` is never called because `this.table == EMPTY_TABLE` is always evaluated to `false`. 
Expression `this.table.length` equals `0` and `this.table.length == EMPTY_TABLE.length` is `true`!!!
If I understand it correctly then if `this.table.length == EMPTY_TABLE.length` is `true` then `this.table == EMPTY_TABLE` should be `true` as well and `inflateTable()` should be called. I got second project with same JDK/Hibernate/GlassFish version and it works just fine in there!
Running on JDK 1.7.0_80 and GlassFish 3.1.1.2.

Any pointers are more than welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -912523107 ... the valid indices for an array vary from 0 to arrayLength-1 . A negative index is not possible.

Comment: Thats the exception from the log :(

Comment: Look at the `hashcode` of the `ChangeLogItem` you are saving in `addToChangeLog` method.

Comment: Well `hashCode` is implemented using `Random.nextInt()` if it helps in any way. This can of course generate even negative numbers but that doesn't matter.

Comment: I meant the individual hashcode that it doesn't work with. And which java version are you using?

Comment: What do u mean by individual? The one in the exception? JDK1.7_80

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, this is caused by calling EJB remote facade.
Even though we are on the same JVM EJB still uses parameter isolation when using @Remote:

"The arguments and results of the methods of the remote business interface are passed by value." source [JSR 318: Enterprise JavaBeans,Version 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1443959730_85a1b350029fb55642342cd1a2c8d1af) page 45, 3.2.1 Remote Clients